# How can I set OverloadedStrings in an ihaskell notebook?

Tags: haskell, ihaskell, overloaded-strings

I understand from the [sample notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/gibiansky/IHaskell/blob/master/notebooks/IHaskell.ipynb) that I should be able to enable and disable extensions as follows:

```
-- We can disable extensions. 
:ext NoEmptyDataDecls 
data Thing

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • ‘Thing’ has no constructors (EmptyDataDecls permits this)
    • In the data declaration for ‘Thing’

-- And enable extensions.
:ext EmptyDataDecls
data Thing
```

However, when I try this with OverloadedStrings, I do not see any success.  You can see from the below that T.lines is looking for String rather than Text. Why?

[image]

What am I misunderstanding or doing wrong?

Comment: [readFile](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=readFile) has type `FilePath -> IO String`. Using `OverloadedStrings` does not magically mean all `String` values turn into `Text` (or `ByteString` etc.), it just makes string *literals* polymorphic. It's just like with numbers, the literal `2`, say, can be any instance of `Num`, but this doesn't mean that you can use a function that returns an `Int` and use its result as if it were a `Double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news: the notebook above does have OverloadedStrings loaded correctly.  The problem is you need to read the file with:

```
T.readFile
```

So

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  text <- T.readFile "./data.txt"
  print $ T.lines text
```

This was confusing because the error highlighted `T.lines` rather than `readFile.` It turns out `readFile` does not produce a form of textual data that will automatically cast to the format required by `T.lines` (it produces `String`, not `Text`).  You had to know that there is an entirely other function to call that does do that. The type system will not convert between these string-like formats for you.  You must do this yourself by calling a file-reading function that explicitly returns a `Text`: here, `T.readFile`.